# Logout link appears duplicated on narrow screens

Tags: bug, user-interface, stack-exchange-button, responsive-design, logout

On narrow screens (typically mobile devices), two logout links are displayed.

> Screenshot:
>
> [image: screenshot]

Comment: For what it's worth, I see the same duplication, both here on MSE and on Stack Overflow; Firefox on iPhone 12 Mini